# How do I go about setting the exact style for tabs in a JTabbedPane?

Tags: java, swing, tabs, jtabbedpane, synth

I have looked around and I cannot figure out how to do it. Should I use the Synth look & feel? How would I go about doing this?

Comment: The style is determined by the Look&Feel. Most L&Fs have ways to tweak them a bit. What exactly do you want to change in the way tabs are presented?

Comment: @jack The tabs in the Eclipse IDE are quite nice, [(Example).](http://files.myopera.com/behrangsa/blog/Eclipse-Tabs.png) I'd like to get something like that.

Comment: Eclipse uses SWT, not Swing. Exactly the same look is not available in Swing AFAIK. You'll need either a different Swing Look&Feel (Synth, Nimbus, Substance, ...) or write your own TabbedPaneUI delegate.

Comment: @jack Brilliant!! I didn't know I could write my own TabbedPaneUI! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [*How to Use Tabbed Panes*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html), [`TabComponentsDemo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html#eg) shows how to put "custom components on tabs."